# Building 32-bit FCGI++ binaries in 64-bit environment in Ubuntu 13

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, fastcgi

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to build 32-bit fcgi++ binaries under my 64-bit env. I configured FCGI++ in the following way:

```
CC="gcc -m32" ./configure
```

After typing 'make' I see the some building process and the following errors at the end (snippet is here):

> gcc -m32 -shared  fcgio.lo  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/home/eotovchits/Downloads/fcgi/fcgi-2.4.1-SNAP-0311112127/libfcgi/.libs -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib  /home/eotovchits/Downloads/fcgi/fcgi-2.4.1-SNAP-0311112127/libfcgi/.libs/libfcgi.so  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libfcgi++.so.0 -o .libs/libfcgi++.so.0.0.0
>   /usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `fcgio.lo' is incompatible with i386 output
>   fcgio.lo: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:74: undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'

...................... a lot of similar lines ...........................

> fcgio.lo: In function `~basic_ios':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:276: undefined reference to`vtable for std::basic_ios >'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:276: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::~ios_base()'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:276: undefined reference to`vtable for std::basic_ios >'
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:276: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::~ios_base()'
>   fcgio.lo: In function`fcgi_istream::~fcgi_istream()':
>   /home/eotovchits/Downloads/fcgi/fcgi-2.4.1-SNAP-0311112127/libfcgi/../include/fcgio.h:120: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
>   /usr/bin/ld: fcgio.lo: file class ELFCLASS64 incompatible with ELFCLASS32
>   /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: File in wrong format
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I assume that I need some additional 32-bits building environment to make the 32-bits binaries (along w/ all the needed 3rd-party libraries, .a-s and .so-s)

Do you know how can i set up such environment locally along with native 64-bit environment and build my fcgi++ binaries for 32-bits environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu you can install the libraries for i386 along the x64 ones by appending":i386" at the end oh the name of the package you want to install (assuming you are using apt-get to install the lib).

here is an example of how to do it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/60751/is-it-possible-to-have-32-bit-libraries-installed-on-a-64-bit-system

And here how to install the compiler for 32 bits (well the STL and other stuff):

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1137-compiling-testing-in-32-bit-on-ubuntu-x86-64